# flake8: Ignore only F401 rule in entire file

Tags: python, flake8

Is there a way to get `flake8` to ignore only a specific rule for an entire file? Specifically, I'd like to ignore just `F401` for an entire file.

I have a file like `__init__.py` where I import symbols that are never used within that file. I'd rather not add `# noqa` to each line. I can add `# flake8: noqa` to the beginning of the file, but that ignores **all** rules. I'd like to ignore **just** the `F401` rule.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

there is not currently a way to do what you're asking with only source inside the file itself

the current suggested way is to use the `per-file-ignores` feature in your `flake8` configuration:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    */__init__.py: F401
```

Note that `F401` in particular can be *solved* in a better way, any names that are exposed in `__all__` will be ignored by `pyflakes`:

```py
from foo import bar  # would potentially trigger F401
__all__ = ('bar',)  # not any more!
```

(disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of `flake8` and one of the maintainers of `pyflakes`)

Comment: I'd say that's less of a disclaimer and more of an authoritative statement :)

Comment: @chepner yep -- unfortunately (or fortunately?) the SO rules require such a disclosure ;)

Comment: OK. That helps. Thanks! Would you consider a feature request for the per-file specification living at the top of the file itself? (If not for `F401` in particular, then maybe for other errors.)

Comment: What's the flake8 file? .flake8.cfg?

Comment: @theX [`setup.cfg`, `tox.ini`, or `.flake8`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations) (found by googling "flake8 configuration files")

Comment: Exporting 3rd party modules as this file public objects on 'import *'. Looks like side effect exploitation. Also might confuse automatic import suggestion in PyCharm and bring cyclic imports.

Comment: Using `__all__` may not be that better. You would have a new spot for inconsistency. See [this discussion](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1551) for example.

Comment: @sourcream you're incorrect -- pyflakes will flag incorrect things in `__all__` if they're mistyped

Comment: @AnthonySottile my point is not that there isn't a tool that can alleviate this. I'm just noting that without `__all__`, I have only one place to put the name of my symbol, while with `__all__` I have two places, and they have to be consistent. So an inconsistency may arise at any time they differ. The discussion I linked to concluded that the use of `__all__` was not really a solution precisely because of that.

Comment: right -- I'm telling you that you're wrong: the inconsistency cannot arise because `pyflakes` enforces that all members in `__all__` are public symbols

Comment: @AnthonySottile we are probably arguing about semantics here. From my perspective, as soon as names differ in `__all__` and `import`, there is an inconsistency, it doesn't matter how clear `pyflakes` will eventually make it after the fact. More inconsistencies mean more maintenance work, and this alone can be the reason a project (like the one I linked to) may not consider using `__all__` a "better way".

Comment: I don't think we're arguing semantics, you're inventing problems that don't exist

Comment: Well, they do exist for people I mentioned and you keep ignoring. Anyway, my comment was really for people not that biased as the maintainer of the library in question. I guess we both know now why SO demands such a disclosure :)

Comment: the people in that thread are unaware of the enforced consistency and don't understand the point of `__all__` which isn't pyflakes specific

Comment: is there a pyflakes equivalent to the per-file-ignores solution?

Comment: pyflakes has no configuration nor options

Comment: I think, using `__all__` is just a bandaid. It looks like it promotes `from module import *` a level up

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Documentation](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html) it's as easy as changing `# noqa` by:

```
# noqa: F401
```

Comment: I thought that was just for a single line, not the entire file. What's the right syntax for the whole file? For instance, `# flake8: noqa: F401` at the top of the file still ignores **all** rules.

Comment: You can run it on the console like this: `flake8 --ignore=F401 your_script.py`

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that syntax, but I'm looking for a way to denote this **in the file**, so that I don't have to modify the command line string.

Comment: @AJFriend Your assumption is correct, that there is no possible syntax to ignore a single rule within a single file declared inside the file.  This answer is incorrect.